# How can I return JSON output when repoze.who authentication fails?

Tags: python, json, authentication, turbogears2, repoze.who

I'm writing a [`repoze.who` plugin](http://repozewho.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins.html#writing-repoze-who-plugins) and want to return JSON from the `repoze.who` authentication middleware and still controll the HTTP status code.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this, is to implement a [`repoze.who` Challenger](http://repozewho.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins.html#challenger-plugins) interface.  The following solution takes advantage of the fact that the [WebOb](http://webob.org/) exceptions, in [`webob.exc`](http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/modules/exceptions.html), can be used as a WSGI application.  The following example shows how this can be used in a hypothetical Facebook plugin, where the [2.x API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/permissions) lets users *not* grant access to their email, which might be required for a successful registration/authentication:

```
import json
from webob.acceptparse import MIMEAccept
from webob.exc import HTTPUnauthorized, HTTPBadRequest


FACEBOOK_CONNECT_REPOZE_WHO_NOT_GRANTED = 'repoze.who.facebook_connect.not_granted'


class ExampleJSONChallengerPlugin(object):
    json_content_type = 'application/json'
    mime_candidates = ['text/html',
                       'application/xhtml+xml',
                       json_content_type,
                       'application/xml',
                       'text/xml']

    def is_json_request_env(self, environ):
        """Checks whether the current request is a json request as deemed by
        TurboGears (i.e. response_type is already set) or if the http
        accept header favours 'application/json' over html.
        """
        if environ['PATH_INFO'].endswith('.json'):
            return True

        if 'HTTP_ACCEPT' not in environ:
            return False

        # Try to mimic what Decoration.lookup_template_engine() does.
        return MIMEAccept(environ['HTTP_ACCEPT']) \
            .best_match(self.mime_candidates) is self.json_content_type

    def challenge(self, environ, status, app_headers, forget_headers):
        if FACEBOOK_CONNECT_REPOZE_WHO_NOT_GRANTED in environ:
            response = HTTPBadRequest(detail={
                'not_granted': 
                environ.pop(FACEBOOK_CONNECT_REPOZE_WHO_NOT_GRANTED),
            })
        elif status.startswith('401 '):
            response = HTTPUnauthorized()
        else:
            response = None

        if response is not None and self.is_json_request_env(environ):
            response.body = json.dumps({
                'code': response.code,
                'status': response.title,
                'explanation': response.explanation,
                'detail': response.detail,
            })
            response.content_type = self.json_content_type

        return response
```

A central point here is that `response`, an instance of a sub-class of `webob.exc.WSGIHTTPException`, is used as a WSGI application, but also that if `response`'s `body` attribute is set, then it is *not* automatically generated, a fact we use to explicitly set the response's body to a JSON-formatted string representation of our dictionary.  If the above challenger is invoked during the handling of a request to a URL ending in '.json' or the `Accept` header includes `application/json`, the body of the response might render as something like:

```
{
    "status": "Bad Request",
    "explanation": "The server could not comply with the request since it is either malformed or otherwise incorrect.",
    "code": 400, 
    "detail": {"not_granted": ["email"]}
}
```

and if not, then the body will be rendered as HTML:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>400 Bad Request</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>400 Bad Request</h1>
  The server could not comply with the request since it is either 
  malformed or otherwise incorrect.<br /><br />
{'not_granted': [u'email']}


 </body>
</html>
```